# Replacing data in many column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I have two excel file 
(1) contain many group names in many column .
(2) contain group name with group id 
 i need to replace all group name in sheet 1 with group id

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not Facebook.  Your post should not just be telling us what you are doing today, it should contain a question and details of what you have already done to try and fix the problem yourself.

Comment: @YowE3K I think you meant Twitter

Comment: @K.Davis 162 characters - can't be Twitter  :D

Comment: @YowE3K It's [280 Characters now](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-switch/wp/2017/11/07/twitter-is-officially-doubling-the-character-limit-to-280/?utm_term=.359be1b8c328). So it's perfect for simple Excel formulas.

Comment: @K.Davis  :O Twice as much reason to not have an account!

Comment: I love these posts. I really love the fact someone thinks it's as easy as this.

Comment: Edit / Replace could do this...

Answer (score -1):

You may use Index Match to solve your issue check this image

Index Match image:

[image: Index Match image]